# Jquery iterating table

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am using following code to iterate table rows with id

```
$('#resultingTableOfSaveDataJS tr').each(function () { //line 1
    var rowID = $(this).id.charAt(6); //line 2
    if (rowID == currentID) { //line 3
        $('#this td').slice(diff); //line 4
    }
});
```

At line 2 i am trying to get the character at 6th position of my each row's id.
But I am getting a Undefined error at line 2.

Please help me to get this code right.

Comment: Try `this.id.charAt(6);`, without jquery wrapper

Comment: Try `this.id.charAt(6);`

Answer (score 1):

each() has parameters that you can use:

```
$('#resultingTableOfSaveDataJS tr').each(function(index, elem){
    var rowID = elem.id.charAt(6);
    if (rowID == currentID){
         $('td', elem).slice(diff);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's either

```
$(this).attr('id').charAt(6); // jQuery
```

Or

```
this.id.charAt(6); // non-jQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using DOM methods on jQuery objects. To get the `id` from a jQuery object:

```
$(this).attr('id').charAt(6);
```

Or:

```
$(this).prop('id').charAt(6);
```

Without jQuery (and JQuery is needless, and over-expensive for this), using the DOM/'plain' JavaScript:

```
this.id.charAt(6);
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: It's valid if you have an element with the `id` of 'this', otherwise you probably want: `$(this).find('td').slice(diff);`